# Angular 2/4 Cannot login user automatically after sign up user

Tags: angular

I am using spring boot for backend, and angular 2/4 for front end, and I am design the sign up page. Once user sign the page up, the web page will sign in user automatically. But currently my page didn't want to login user automatically after user sign up...

Here is the code for `auth.service.ts`, auth service perform `sign up`, `login`, `logout` operation

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private config: ConfigService,
  ) { }

  login(user) {
    const loginHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    const body = `username=${user.username}&password=${user.password}`;
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.login_url, body, loginHeaders).map(() => {
      console.log("Login success");
      this.userService.getMyInfo().subscribe();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Login error");
      return Observable.throw(error);
    })
  }

  signup(user){
    const signupHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.signup_url, JSON.stringify(user), signupHeaders).map(() =>{
      console.log("Sign up success" + JSON.stringify(user));
      this.login(user);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error");
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
    });
  }

  logout() {
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.logout_url, {})
      .map(() => {
        this.userService.currentUser = null;
      });
  }

  changePassowrd(passwordChanger) {
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.change_password_url, passwordChanger);
  }

}
```

So what I did wrong on this code? If I only call login, it works

**Updated on DEC 18:**

Here is the screen shot for the chrome console
[image]

Also, here is the code for `signup.component.ts`

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DisplayMessage } from '../shared/models/display-message';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {
  UserService,
  AuthService
} from '../service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/SUbject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'Sign up';
  githubLink = 'https://github.com/bfwg/angular-spring-starter';
  form: FormGroup;

  /**
   * Boolean used in telling the UI
   * that the form has been submitted
   * and is awaiting a response
   */
  submitted = false;

  /**
   * Notification message from received
   * form request or router
   */
  notification: DisplayMessage;

  returnUrl: string;
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe((params: DisplayMessage) => {
      this.notification = params;
    });
    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(64)])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(32)])],
      firstname:[''],
      lastname: ['']
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  repository() {
    window.location.href = this.githubLink;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    /**
     * Innocent until proven guilty
     */
    this.notification = undefined;
    this.submitted = true;

    this.authService.signup(this.form.value)
    // show me the animation
    .delay(1000)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.authService.login(this.form.value);
      this.userService.getMyInfo().subscribe();
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    },
    error => {
      this.submitted = false;
      this.notification = { msgType: 'error', msgBody: 'Sign up failed' };
    });

  }


}
```

Comment: When you debug your code, where exactly does this fail? And any error messages?

Comment: @AJT_82 I updated the original question

Answer (score 1):

Seems like found the solutions...

Here is the code snippet for what I did:
In `signup.component.ts`:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DisplayMessage } from '../shared/models/display-message';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {
  UserService,
  AuthService
} from '../service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/SUbject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'Sign up';
  githubLink = 'https://github.com/bfwg/angular-spring-starter';
  form: FormGroup;

  /**
   * Boolean used in telling the UI
   * that the form has been submitted
   * and is awaiting a response
   */
  submitted = false;

  /**
   * Notification message from received
   * form request or router
   */
  notification: DisplayMessage;

  returnUrl: string;
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe((params: DisplayMessage) => {
      this.notification = params;
    });
    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(64)])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(32)])],
      firstname:[''],
      lastname: ['']
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  repository() {
    window.location.href = this.githubLink;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    /**
     * Innocent until proven guilty
     */
    this.notification = undefined;
    this.submitted = true;

    this.authService.signup(this.form.value)
    // show me the animation
    .delay(1000)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.authService.login(this.form.value).subscribe(data =>{
        this.userService.getMyInfo().subscribe();
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      })
    },
    error => {
      this.submitted = false;
      this.notification = { msgType: 'error', msgBody: 'Sign up failed' };
    });

  }


}
```

In `auth.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private config: ConfigService,
  ) { }

  login(user) {
    const loginHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    const body = `username=${user.username}&password=${user.password}`;
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.login_url, body, loginHeaders).map(() => {
      console.log("Login success");
      this.userService.getMyInfo().subscribe();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Login error" + error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    })
  }

  signup(user){
    const signupHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.signup_url, JSON.stringify(user), signupHeaders).map(() =>{
      console.log("Sign up success");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Sign up error" + error.json());
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
    });
  }

  logout() {
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.logout_url, {})
      .map(() => {
        this.userService.currentUser = null;
      });
  }

  changePassowrd(passwordChanger) {
    return this.apiService.post(this.config.change_password_url, passwordChanger);
  }

}
```

On my backend code I add my code for signup part in `UserController`

```
  @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/signup")
  public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

    User existUser = this.userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if (existUser != null) {
      return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    List<Authority> auths = this.authService.findByname("ROLE_USER"); // this.authService.findById(2L);

    user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setAuthorities(auths);
    this.userService.save(user);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/api/user/{userId}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
    // return user;
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

It works fine, but one more issue... If user sign up and login successfully, then user try to do another sign up, it got `POST http://localhost:4200/api/signup (403 Forbidden)`, I don't know how to fix this issue at the moment...